# AttributeError: 'CSVupload' object has no attribute 'urls'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
    class AdminProduct(models.Model):
      productname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      barcode     = models.BigIntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.productname

    class CSVupload(models.Model):
      csv         = models.FileField(upload_to='product/',null=True,blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
  from django.contrib import admin
  from .models import AdminProduct
  from .models import CSVupload
  # Register your models here.

  admin.site.register(AdminProduct,CSVupload)
```

Want to register two models in admin,AdminProduct and CSVupload.
Getting an error :- AttributeError: 'CSVupload' object has no attribute 'urls'.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to `register()` is a ModelAdmin class. If you want to register multiple models at once, without specific ModelAdmins, you should pass them as an interable in the first parameter:

```
admin.site.register([AdminProduct, CSVupload])
```